# Let A and B be nonempty and upper bounded real sets. Prove supA < supB

Tags: supremum-and-infimum, upper-lower-bounds

Let A and B be nonempty and upper bounded real sets.

Suppose That exists $\epsilon > 0$ so for all $ a \in A$ exists $ b \in B$ 
so that $a + \epsilon < b$

> Prove that $\sup A <  \sup B $

and if we suppose that for every $ a \in A$ exists $\epsilon > 0$  and  $ b \in B$ such that $a + \epsilon < b$. Will necessarily be $\sup A <  \sup B $ ?

I think that the first one is false because let $ A = B = (0,1) $ so there is  $\epsilon > 0$ so for all $ a \in A$ exists $ b \in B$ 
so that $a + \epsilon < b$ but  $\sup A =  \sup B =1 $.

Is that correct ? if not how to prove it ?
and about the second one is that true or false and why?

thanks

Comment: Be careful of the quantifiers!

Answer (score 2):

Your example works for the second question but not for the first: if we take $a =1-\epsilon$ the there is no $b \in B$ with $a+\epsilon =1 <b$.

To prove the first result note that for  all $a \in A$ there exist $b \in B$such that $a <b-\epsilon $.  This implies that $a <\sup B-\epsilon $. Since this holds for all $a \in A$ we get $sup A \leq \sup B-\epsilon $ Hence $sup A <\sup B$